# How to integrate spring profiles in Spring Boot 2.4+ application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-2

My current spring boot 2.3 and below config files are

- `application.properties`
- `application-dev.properties`
- `application-qa.properties`
- `application-prod.properties`
- `application-local.properties`

I have to include the profile `onlyLocal` in my `local` profile and I have to include `cloudProfile` in all other profiles.

For spring boot 2.4+, I found that putting the below in my `application.properties` file works:

```
spring.profiles.group.local=local,onlyLocal
spring.profiles.group.dev=dev,cloudProfile
spring.profiles.group.qa=qa,cloudProfile
spring.profiles.group.prod=prod,cloudProfile
```

My question is, is there a better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using groups to aggregate multiple profile files into one profile is perfectly sound and agrees very nicely with the intentions of the Spring Boot team: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

Generally, you should think about whether the complexity of profile groups is really worth it. If the profiles `cloudProfile` and `onlyLocal` only yield a handful of properties, then it might make more sense to just copy them into the respective properties files. If the two profiles do contain a lot of properties, then the complexity is warranted and allows you to avoid duplication.

Another mechanism to import properties files into other properties files is using `spring.config.import`. But it's really doing the same with a different mechanism.

Comment: The profiles are from my pom dependencies, so no way to copy them into existing property files. Thanks

Comment: how to combine configserver and multiple property files?